# Trigger Google Tag Manager jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given my code uses jQuery extensively, can I indeed fire a call/trigger to Google Tag Manager at some point on an `if` Javascript statement on my website?

Comment: Removed unnecessary words and rephrased

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? We have been struggling for days with a very similar concept as yours and what @user3550203 suggested. Nothing seem to work.

Comment: I remember that @user3550203's response should work. You have to make sure the Tag Event matches the name and you have all plugins loaded in your website/app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to fire an a trigger based on your jquery if statement?

You will have to add a dataLayer that contains an event on your if statement. For example;

```
if(condition) {
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'ifEvent'
});
} 
else {
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'elseEvent'
});
}
```

Than you can create trigger in google tag manager by selecting "custom event" as trigger type, on Event name, you can put 'ifEvent' or 'elseEvent' what ever you need to fire.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Comment: It is probably better to use `window.dataLayer` instead of just `dataLayer` to avoid the possibility of variable name conflicts.  And you should perhaps make sure that `dataLayer` exists first, i.e. `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];` before calling `window.dataLayer.push()`.

Comment: We are trying to basically do the same thing. If successful login send this event. Else if failed login send this other event. We have added very similar dataLayer snippets as described above (and also followed @Stefan advice). But, GTM never seems to receive our events? We promote the code live and then are testing in the GTM test environment.